# Java implementation to check for the point of intersection between 2 line segments?

Tags: java, geometry

I need to calculate the point of intersection between two line segments. I did a lot of searching and came up with the below method, but am finding it to be unreliable. I think this is because the method doesn't take into account any error or tolerance. Can anyone point me to a good Java implementation of this?

```
private Point2D intersection(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4) 
{
    //add some tolerance 
    double tol = 1;
    if(x1 < x2)
    {
        x1 -= tol;
        x2 += tol;
    }
    else
    {
        x1 += tol;
        x2 -= tol;
    }
    if(x3 < x4)
    {
        x3 -= tol;
        x4 += tol;
    }
    else
    {
        x3 += tol;
        x4 -= tol;
    }
    if(y1 < y2)
    {
        y1 -= tol;
        y2 += tol;
    }
    else
    {
        y1 += tol;
        y2 -= tol;
    }
    if(y3 < y4)
    {
        y3 -= tol;
        y4 += tol;
    }
    else
    {
        y3 += tol;
        y4 -= tol;
    }
    
    
    double d = (x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4);
    if (d == 0) 
    {
        return null;
    }
        
    double xi = ((x3-x4)*(x1*y2-y1*x2)-(x1-x2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/d;
    double yi = ((y3-y4)*(x1*y2-y1*x2)-(y1-y2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/d;
    
    double minx12 = Math.min(x1, x2);
    double maxx12 = Math.max(x1, x2);
    double minx34 = Math.min(x3, x4);
    double maxx34 = Math.max(x3, x4);
    double miny12 = Math.min(y1, y2);
    double maxy12 = Math.max(y1, y2);
    double miny34 = Math.min(y3, y4);
    double maxy34 = Math.max(y3, y4);
    
    if(xi < minx12 || xi > maxx12 || xi < minx34 || xi > maxx34 ||
            yi < miny12 || yi > maxy12 || xi < miny34 || xi > maxy34)
    {
        return null;
    }
        
    return new Point2D.Double(xi,yi);
}
```

Comment: You should always try to be specific and precise around here. Saying it is "unreliable" is not very helpful to people who want to help you. Describe what, exactly, is unreliable. For example, a use case where this method returns a wrong value, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you consider "unreliable", here are two errors:

1) You are extending the segments into infinite lines, finding their intersection, and then seeing if that intersection point's x and y values lie between the x and y values of *one* of your segments. You should compare it to the x and y values of *both* segments.

Consider these two segments: (1,0)-(0,1) and (1,1)-(2,2). Your formula calculates `xi` and `yi` to both be 0.5, which is perfectly correct. You check 0.5 lies between 1,0 and 0,1 - and it does. But it does not lie between 1 and 2.

In other words, your intersection point is on *one* of the segments, but it is not on the *other* segment.

2) You should also consider that `x1` will not always be less than `x2` etc. As in my example above, y1 < y2 but x1 > x2. And if you flip the endpoints then the reverse will be true.